# "Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively", when running on xampp

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error. dont know why. just installed xampp. my code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: _"because the target machine actively on xampp"_ - That's a new error message! I'm guessing it's _"because the target machine actively refused it"_?

Comment: Have you checked that MySQL is up and running?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no mine is different. i have not created any username and i am runnining in Windows with the default username of xampp.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how to do that? well doesnt MySQL come with xampp or do i haveto install.

Comment: Just because it get's installed doesn't mean it's started. Read the manual for xampp.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how to check if started.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how  do i close the question? i got the answer.

Comment: Write an answer explaining what you did and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer. I just had to keep the mysql_start.bat file open while using sql.